# Code first Model foreign key property SocialDetails is null even when the ID's match in the DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, visual-studio-2012, dbcontext

I'm trying to debug a DBContext query and the generated SQL looks like this

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[SocialDetails_Id] AS [SocialDetails_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
```

However the foreign key property SocialDetails is null even when I've checked the ID's in teh DB

```
 public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }

          [Required]
        public User User { get; set; }

          [Required]
        public SocialDetails SocialDetails { get; set; }
etc
```

What is the best way to find out why the SocialDetails is always null?

Comment: could you show the dbcontext code ?

Comment: Really need to see the C# query against the DbContext - my guess would be that you need to add an .Include("SocialDetails") to your query.

Comment: @Cybermaxs    var query = from c in context.Item where c.Id == ItemId select c;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have lazy loading disabled.

As suggested by Matt Whetton, try to do something like this:

```
var items = from x in dbContext.Items.Include("SocialDetails")
            where x.Id = id
            select x;
```

where dbContext is your context, and you have a DbSet named Items

See also this link (MSDN):

[Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896272%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It depends on every case. I suggest you to read the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx